# pass parameters to bootstrap modal from an elements list with pagination

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, pagination

I work on a node.js app and I have a list of n elements in an ejs view.
It contains filters, pagination, ...

Every element have an "edit" action. And when user clicks on "edit" button, a modal window with element's data is displayed.

My problem is with no pagination for the list, it works good.

But with pagination (e.g. 10 elements / page), only the 10 first elements will have modal working good...

Example of the generated list code with elem n°10 (works) and n°11 (not works) :

```
<tr class="even">       
  <td class=" ">Abella Sàrl</td>
  <td class=" ">10 Rue du Village L-6585 Steinheim (Steenem)</td>
  <td class=" ">
    <a href="#editMarkerModal" data-toggle="modal">
      <i class="fa fa-edit editMarker" data-marker="{"address":"10 Rue du Village  L-6585 Steinheim (Steenem)","longitude":null,"latitude":null,"name":"Abella Sàrl","_user":"5305051a6f2529844824c1c5","_id":"53077ef91f85d2c752f1cb50","uptade_date":"2014-02-21T16:29:45.175Z","create_date":"2014-02-21T16:29:45.175Z","active":true,"spritesheet_y":null,"spritesheet_x":null,"logo":"default","__v":0}"></i>
    </a>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr class="odd">
  <td class=" ">Action Line SA</td>
  <td class=" ">28 Route de Longwy L-8080 Bertrange (Bartreng)</td>
  <td class=" ">
    <a href="#editMarkerModal" data-toggle="modal">
      <i class="fa fa-edit editMarker" data-marker="{"address":"28 Route de Longwy L-8080 Bertrange (Bartreng)","longitude":null,"latitude":null,"name":"Action Line SA","_user":"5305051a6f2529844824c1c5","_id":"53077ef81f85d2c752f1ca18","uptade_date":"2014-02-21T16:29:44.720Z","create_date":"2014-02-21T16:29:44.720Z","active":true,"spritesheet_y":null,"spritesheet_x":null,"logo":"default","__v":0}"></i>
    </a>
  </td>
</tr>
```

My Jquery code for test :

```
$('.editMarker').on('click', function() {
    var marker = $(this).data('marker');        
    alert(marker.name);              
});
```

Appreciate your help.
C.

Comment: see my answer. According to details that you will provide, I can refactor my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click paginate button, probably you are getting next 10 elements with ajax. In your success function of ajax call, you can use following initialization code for bootstrap modal;

```
$('a[data-toggle="modal"]').modal();
```

If you are not using ajax, no problem. Just put above code in your pageinate button click event.

**Update:** Added example;

You can add function to paginate event to re-init modal;

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable({"sPaginationType": "full_numbers", "iDisplayLength":2});
    initModal();

    $(".dataTables_paginate").find("a").on("click", function() {
            initModal();
    })

    function initModal() {
        $('.mymodal').on("click", function() {
        $('.modal').modal('hide');
        $("#modal-content").html(JSON.stringify($(this).find(".editMarker").data("marker")));
            $('.modal').modal();
    });
    }
});
```

Here is a working example: [**http://jsfiddle.net/HEDvf/1137/**](http://jsfiddle.net/HEDvf/1137/)

Comment: For pagination, I use jquery.dataTables-cust.js. No ajax, all data are loaded when refresh the page. Here is the code for the pagination : [http://jsfiddle.net/zJMjM](http://jsfiddle.net/zJMjM) TY

Comment: @ceadreak I have added working example, see my updated answer

Comment: No, I don't have any error ... I check your example. tks

Comment: I think it's another problem. When I add this event `$('.pagination a').on('click', function() { alert('pass'); });` it works good the first time, when I click on a page link. Second time it's dead ...

Comment: It is OK in my example, you are talking about your example right?

Comment: Yes it's for my example. I solved strangely the problem. My javascript definitions (functions, jquery, ...) are at the end of my layout. If I move them on the <head> section, it works ... An idea ??

Comment: Yes, your jquery datatable converts your table to formatted table. If your code at the end of the page, it cannot find other pages to apply modal thing. When you move it to head, it applies modal to all rows of tables. I assumed that you are using your code at the top of your page  before jqdatatable. My example was working, I couldn't understand why your not working

Comment: It works now, with the jquery call in the <head> section. don't know really why coz' in all cases, the call of datatable.js was after the jquery call. So ... Mystery :) Thanks a lot Hüseyin !